# What is the complexity of complex matrix multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, asymptotics, matrix-calculus

I want to calculate the complexity of an algorithm in MATLAB (not the time complexity), however, all the matrices are complex ones. I guess that the complexity of complex matrix multiplication is higher, due to the more operations required by the multiplication of complex numbers compared to real ones. Does anyone have an answer? I would like to know the same for the inversion of a complex matrix. Anyone has documentation on these or knows the big O?

In particular, I am looking for the complexity of $(A^H A)^{-1}$. A is a complex $M\times N$ matrix.

Comment: If you are not looking at time complexity (i.e. the number of steps), then what are you looking at? At space complexity? 
Aside: Multiplication is usually quadratic (depending on the length of the number), or a bit better (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations). Addition is linear. Thus, complex number multiplication is only linearily more complicated then real number multiplication.  I don't know about the inverse. Depends on the algorithm propably - but it shouldn't make a big difference, wether you're working over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @Guenterino: "or a bit better": $O(n\log n)$ is _much_ better than $O(n^2)$.

Comment: @Guenterino I am looking for the big O(). I thought time-complexity refers to the actual time in seconds that it takes to get the result, aka cpu-time. So you are telling me that no matter what the matrix is (real- or complex-valued), the complexity is the same?

Comment: So... Since the multiplication I posted results in the inversion of a $N\times N$ matrix, is the complexity $O(N^{3})$ even though we are dealing with complex numbers?

Comment: Multiplication of two complex numbers involves 4 multiplications of real numbers and 2 additions (assuming the complex numbers are in the usual form $a+ib$). So the number of steps would increase by only a constant factor; with O( ) it won't change at all.

Comment: @TonyK you're obviously right. I didn't quite remember anymore and didn't read the Wikipedia article; just added it for reference. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @bigboss Usually, when talking about time-complexity this refers to the number of steps. It is done this way because cpu-time makes no sense, as it is not standardised. You would get a different time on every computer. The number of steps, though, is always the same (if the algorithm is the same).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to quickly type an answer here, even though almost everything has been said in the comments. As Andreas Blass already wrote: Multiplication of two complex numbers involves 4 multiplications and 2 additions of real numbers. Thus, if $f$ is the complexity of multiplying two real numbers, the complexity of multiplying two complex numbers is less than $6f$, which is still in $\mathcal{O}(f)$. You will, usually, be able to consider $f$ to be a constant, as you have a maximal size that your numbers are allowed to have (float, double, etc.). If you don't restrict number size, you have to consider the largest number in your matrix and the size of your matrix when calculating the complexity.

So, for the naive algorithm, the complexity of multiplying two matrices is going to be $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$, no matter whether it's complex or real numbers. I don't know what algorithm you use for calculating the inverse, but the same argument propably applies there: multiplication and addition within the complex numbers is going to have constant complexity and, thus, will not affect the computational complexity.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. So returning to my original question and taking into account your reply an algorithm doing this operation : $(A^HA)^{−1}$ (complex valued A $M\times N$) i.e., finding conjugate transpose, multiply with A and then invert  has an overall complexity $O(N^3)$ ? Is this correct? I do not use a custom made algorithm to invert. I am using Matlab's inversion algorithm.

Comment: If the same algorithm has complexity $\mathcal{O}(N^3)$ over $\mathbb{R}$, I would assume that it is correct.